# Creating a dummy/indicator variable that references date variables from two different data frames

Tags: r, date, dplyr, conditional-statements, dummy-variable

My problem is quite basic, but I'm new to R and I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple of days now without any success :(

### What I'm working with

This is the **CoronaNet_cleaned** data frame.

```
country       date_start  date_end  
South Africa  2020-03-22  NA
South Africa  2020-04-12  2020-06-02
Australia     2021-02-11  2020-04-12
Australia     2020-06-10  NA 
United States 2020-01-01  NA  
United States 2020-12-08  NA
```

This is the **tweetgovuser** data  frame

```
country        screen_name  created_at   text                 
South Africa   HealthZA     2020-12-08   The number of health care workers....
...
```

### What I want

I want to create a column in **tweetgovuser** called **lockdown_dummy**. I want this indicator/dummy variable to be created based off of three conditions:

- if **created_at** (tweetgovuser) matches **date_start** or **date_end** (CoronaNet_cleaned), let **lockdown_dummy** (in tweetgovuser) = 1
- if **created_at** is between the dates of **date_end** and **date_start**, let **lockdown_dummy** = 1
- If none of the above conditions are true, let **lockdown_dummy** = 0

The end product should look like this:

```
country        screen_name  created_at   text             lockdown_dummy      
South Africa   HealthZA     2020-12-08   The number....   1
...
```

### What I've tried

I've tried several different blocks of code but recently I've written this very crude and clearly poorly written code to execute this:

```
  lockdown_dummy <- case_when(
  created_at == date_start ~ 1,
  created_at == date_end ~ 1, 
  "date_start" %<% created_at %<% "date_end" ~ 1
  TRUE ~ 0
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. Next time, try to share more data with some importing code so that it is easier for us to make experiments. You can use functions like `dput()` for this.

In your case, the first thing to do is to join the two tables. Here I used `left_join()`.

Then, you only need a call to `ifelse()` to check if the date is higher than the start and lesser than the end.

Here is the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

CoronaNet_cleaned = read.table(header=T, text="
country       date_start  date_end  
'South Africa'  2020-03-22  NA
'South Africa'  2020-03-22  2027-03-22
'South Africa'  2020-04-12  2020-06-02
Australia     2021-02-11  2020-04-12
Australia     2020-06-10  NA 
'United States' 2020-01-01  NA  
'United States' 2020-12-08  NA")

tweetgovuser  = read.table(header=T, text="
country        screen_name  created_at   text                 
'South Africa'   HealthZA     2020-12-08   'The number of health care workers'                
")

CoronaNet_cleaned %>% 
  left_join(tweetgovuser, by="country") %>% 
  mutate(
    date_start = ymd(date_start),  #probably not needed with real data
    date_end = ymd(date_end),      #probably not needed with real data
    created_at = ymd(created_at),  #probably not needed with real data
    dummy = ifelse(created_at>=date_start & created_at<=date_end, 1, 0),
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 x 7
#>   country    date_start date_end   screen_name created_at text             dummy
#>   <chr>      <date>     <date>     <chr>       <date>     <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 South Afr~ 2020-03-22 NA         HealthZA    2020-12-08 The number of h~    NA
#> 2 South Afr~ 2020-03-22 2027-03-22 HealthZA    2020-12-08 The number of h~     1
#> 3 South Afr~ 2020-04-12 2020-06-02 HealthZA    2020-12-08 The number of h~     0
#> 4 Australia  2021-02-11 2020-04-12 <NA>        NA         <NA>                NA
#> 5 Australia  2020-06-10 NA         <NA>        NA         <NA>                NA
#> 6 United St~ 2020-01-01 NA         <NA>        NA         <NA>                NA
#> 7 United St~ 2020-12-08 NA         <NA>        NA         <NA>                NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: here's the actual data if that helps: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MBNLh8iAiT2UUGuofuVxXlcXcM8AW9YZ?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, really for taking the time to write this out. I can see you joined the tables by 'country'. What happens though is that in the output, for the column below, it ends up looking something like this: https://imgur.com/a/S1Mnawq

It doesn't makes sense to join rows that refer to something in march 14 2021.  with another that is between march 18 and April 16 2020. Would that mean I should join by dates AND country???